# How to configure a SharePoint list to only allow value for a column when another column contains to a specified value

Tags: list

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I want a column named "Unit" to only allow a value when a column named "Position" contains a value of **Primary**.

The column named "Unit" is a drop down box that has enforce unique value but not required
The column named "Position" is a drop down box that values are not require nor is unique values enforced.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 and 2013 you can use validation formulas to accomplish what you are wanting to do.  This post has a good overview of how to use validation formulas: http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/sharepoint-2010-list-improvements-column-validation-and-list-validation-settings/.  And this page has a good set of examples for how to create your formula: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx.

Something like:

```
=OR([Unit]="", [Position]="Primary")
```